# Getting an object reference by name from a DataTemplate

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

If I have the following XAML:

```
<toolkit:DataForm Height="100"  x:Name="form">
        <toolkit:DataForm.EditTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Name="stack"></StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </toolkit:DataForm.EditTemplate>
    </toolkit:DataForm>
```

I can get a reference to "form" by this.FindName("form") from the View.

How can I get a reference to "stack"? FindName returns null.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is that the xaml content of a `DataTemplate` belongs to a different NameScope than the outer Xaml.  Calling `FindName` on an element searches only the NameScope in which the element was originally generated.  Hence calling `FindName` on the `UserControl` will not find elements generated by a `DataTemplate`.  The reason for this is that `DataTemplate` (and other templates) are designed to be reused multiple times, the use of NameScope disambiguates the names.

The solution is to invoke the help of the `VisualTreeHelper`, have a look at the code in this [blog](http://geekswithblogs.net/codingbloke/archive/2010/12/19/visual-tree-enumeration.aspx) for my take on `VisualTreeHelper`.  With the `VisualTreeEnumeration` class from that blog added to your project you can do this:-

```
var element = this.Descendents().OfType<FrameworkElement>().FirstOrDefault(fe => fe.Name == "stack");
```

Of course if you know that "stack" is a `StackPanel` then you can get more specific with `.OfType<T>`.